# ¿Cómo definir vistas distintas según el rol de usuario?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

En mi aplicación de Laravel tengo 2 roles de usuario, en la base de datos tengo una columna con el nombre de rol, en el que el usuario puede ser `admin` o `normal`, estoy intentando que cuando accedo al `/home` despues del **login**, cuando entre el usuario normal me redirija a una página en concreto, he probado haciendo el método en el controlador, reescribiendo el metodo redirect, pero la verdad que mucho caso no me hace.

```
public function redirectPath()
    {
        //$user = Auth::user()->with('rol')->get();
        if (Auth::user()->rol =='admin') {
            dd(Auth::user());
        }
        return '/vacation/request';
    }
```

Edito: También quería ocultar el menú lateral al usuario normal, he probado con el registro de session digamos, pero me lo oculta todo también al usuario administrador

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if ($_SESSION[Auth::user] == "USUARIO_ADMIN") { ?>

 <li><a href="dashboard-crm.html" data-i18n="nav.dash.crm" class="menu-item">Vacaciones</a>
                        <ul class="menu-content">
                            <li><a href="{{url('/vacation/request')}}" data-i18n="nav.menu_levels.solic" class="menu-item">Ver solicitudes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="{{url('/vacation/calendar')}}" data-i18n="nav.menu_levels.solic" class="menu-item">Ver calendario</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                   <?php } ?>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/vacation/create/'.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id).'/'.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->name)) }}" data-i18n="nav.dash.crm" class="menu-item">Solicitar Vacaciones</a></li>
```

Me oculta sin problema los menus pero no puedo loguearme y al admin tambien.

**EDITO**

Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas, vamos a organizarnos un poquito, respecto al `middleware`, tengo uno que me diferencia las redirecciones por decirlo de algun modo, es el siguiente: 
Para el usuario admin:

```
class MDusuarioadmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $usuario_actual=\Auth::user();
        if($usuario_actual->tipoUsuario!=1){
         return view("mensajes.msj_rechazado")->with("msj","No tiene suficientes Privilegios para acceder a esta seccion");
        }
        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

y para el usuario normal:

```
class MDusuariostandard
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $usuario_actual=\Auth::user();
        if($usuario_actual->tipoUsuario!=2){
         return view("mensajes.msj_rechazado")->with("msj","Esta seccion es solo visible para el usuario estandard <br/> usted aun no ha sido asignado como usuario standard , consulte al administrador del sistema");
        }
        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

Pero los uso para digamos bloquear el acceso a las páginas que el usuario normal no podría ver.

Bien respecto a mis rutas las tengo definidas asi:

```
//rutas accessibles slo si el usuario no se ha logueado
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {

    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', ['as' =>'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']); 
    // Registration routes...
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('register', ['as' => 'auth/register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']);


});

//rutas accessibles solo si el usuario esta autenticado y ha ingresado al sistema
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    //Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    //Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);
    //Route::get('listado_usuarios/{page?}', 'UsuariosController@listado_usuarios');

});

//rutas accessibles solo para el usuario administrador
Route::group(['middleware' => 'usuarioAdmin'], function () {

    Route::get('/worker/create', 'WorkerController@create');
    Route::post('/worker/store', 'WorkerController@store');
    Route::post('/worker/upload',  ['as' => 'worker.upload', 'uses' => 'WorkerController@upload']);
    Route::get('/worker/show/{id_worker}', 'WorkerController@show');
    Route::get('/worker/edit/{id_worker}', 'WorkerController@edit');
    Route::post('/worker/update', 'WorkerController@update');
    Route::get('/worker/retirados', 'WorkerController@retirados');
    Route::post('/worker/remove', 'WorkerController@remove');
    Route::get('/worker/showall', 'WorkerController@showall');

    Route::get('/area', 'AreaController@index');
    Route::get('/area/create', 'AreaController@create');
    Route::post('/area/store', 'AreaController@store');

    Route::get('/vacation/create/{id_worker}/{name_worker}', 'VacationController@create');
    Route::post('/vacation/store', 'VacationController@store');
    Route::get('/vacation/calendar', 'VacationController@index');
    Route::get('/vacation/create', 'VacationController@index');
    Route::get('/vacation/request', 'VacationController@solicitudes');
    Route::get('/vacation/update', 'VacationController@update');
});
//rutas accessibles solo para el usuario standard
Route::group(['middleware' => 'usuarioStandard'], function () { 

    Route::get('/vacation/create/{id_worker}/{name_worker}', 'VacationController@create');
    Route::post('/vacation/store', 'VacationController@store');
    Route::get('/vacation/calendar', 'VacationController@index');
    Route::get('/vacation/create', 'VacationController@index');

});
```

y en mi controlador tengo esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class AuthController extends Controller
{


use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration & Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
| authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
| a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
|
*/

protected $redirctTo ='/';

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */

//login
protected function getLogin()
{
    return view("login");
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    Session::put('tipoUsuario', 'admin');
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    { 
        $usuarioactual=\Auth::user();
       return view('home')->with("usuario",  $usuarioactual);
    }

    return "credenciales incorrectas";
}

//registro   
protected function getRegister()
{
    return view("registro");
}

protected function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = $request;

    $user=new User;
    $user->name=$data['name'];
    $user->email=$data['email'];
    $user->password=bcrypt($data['password']);

    if($user->save())
    {
         return "se ha registrado correctamente el usuario";
    }
}

//registro
protected function getLogout()
{
    $this->auth->logout();

    Session::flush();

    return redirect('login');
}



}
```

He probado a añadir lo de la SESSION en el controlador pero solo me devuelve si o si las rutas del admin, aunque ponga el if tal cual en la vista y la linea que me propuso Nicolas,
Lo de la redireccion sigue sin funcionar va al home y punto, he probado distintas formas pero siempre obtengo el mismo resultado, sea admin o normal me redirije al home y punto, de veras que muchisimas gracias a todos por vuestras propuestas.

Edito 2: utilizo la version 5.2, influye mucho? de hecho usaba la 5.1 y lo actualize a la 5.2

Comment: Según veo en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#included-authenticating el método que tienes que sobre escribir es `redirectTo()` en lugar de `redirectPath`

Comment: En cuanto a la segunda cuestión, haz un `if` igual al que haces en el controlador. Te recomiendo utilizar blade para las vistas. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Comment: podrías especificar un middleware que controle el acceso al inicio, en el caso de que sea usuario normal  le de paso a que siga a la ruta inicio, y que el controlador de inicio te redireccione a la pagina para usuario normal, y si el middleware detecta que eres usuario tipo admin te redireccione a donde tu deseas

Comment: @JeanCarlosHernandez te edite la respuesta añadiendo un ejemplo para Laravel 5.2, el primer ejemplo que te di era para Laravel >=5.4, y aun que es todo muy similar han cambiado algunas cosillas, vamos ya por la version 5.5 recomendable utilizar simpre la ultima versión cuando se empieza un proyecto nuevo o actualizar si es posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una alternativa para **redireccionar** el login según el tipo de usuario, es la siguiente:

1) Por un lado, cuando se loguea cualquier usuario, indicar que se lo redireccione a una url.

Esto se hace en el archivo `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php`, indicando la variable `protected $redirectTo = '/';` dentro de la definición de la clase.

(con el valor de la variable que se desee, en este caso elegí la raíz).

2) Y luego, en el archivo `routes.php`, agregar la siguiente condición:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if( Auth::user() ) //se valida si esta logueado
        if( Auth::user()->rol =='admin' ) //se valida el tipo de usuario
            return redirect('/admin');
        else
            return redirect('/normal');
    else
        return redirect('/login');
});
```

Y por supuesto, definir las rutas "admin" y "normal" en `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('admin','LoginController@admin');
Route::get('normal','LoginController@normal');
```

(habría que revisar el caso, pero se puede redireccionar directamente a las vistas correspondientes).

--

Con respecto a **ocultar** items en el menú, según el tipo de usuario, recomendaría hacer lo siguiente:

1) Definir una variable de sesión en el controller, por ejemplo, en `LoginController@admin` (es decir, en el método admin del controller LoginController), definir `Session::put('tipoUsuario', 'admin');`.

2) Y en la vista, instanciar directamente a dicha variable de sesión:

```
@if( Session::get('tipoUsuario') == 'admin' )
    <h1>admin</h1>
@else
    <h1>normal</h1>
@endif
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Como indique en los comentarios y viendo que las respuestas se han encaminado en otra dirección solo tienes que sobre escribir el método `redirecTo()` en lugar de `redirecPath()` como estas haciendo y retornar el nombre se la ruta como un `string`. La ruta del controlador donde puedes sobreescribir el metodo es por defecto en: `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

Ejemplo Laravel >= 5.4.*:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /* Ruta de redireccion por defecto */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
    *-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    * Creamos el método redirectTo()
    *-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    *
    * Esta función nos permite redirigir al iniciar sesión 
    * en función de la lógica de nustra aplicación.
    *
    * La ruta retornada en retornada en este método redirectTo(), 
    * prevalece sobre la propiedad $redirectTo declarada al principio.
    *
    * @return string
    *
    */

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        if(\Auth::user()->rol == 'admin')
        {
            return '/admin';
        } else {
            return '/home';
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

En **Laravel 5.2.*** podemos sobreescribir la función `redirectPath()` para hacer lo mismo, el controlador donde tenemos que sobreescribirla es en `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php`

Ejemplo Laravel 5.2.*:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if(\Auth::user()->rol == 'admin')
    {
        return '/admin';
    } else {
        return '/home';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente en modelo User.php yo tengo lo siguientes Roles:

```
const ADMIN = 'ADMIN';
const EDITOR = 'EDITOR';
const MODERATOR = 'MODERATOR';
const TEACHER = 'TEACHER';
const STUDENT = 'STUDENT';

public function isAdmin() {
    return $this->role === User::ADMIN;
}
```

Creo desde la terminal crear un Middleware para proteger mis rutas por ejemplo las rutas para solamente el admin:

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

En el método handle del Middleware que acabo de crear hago la siguiente lógica:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!auth()->check()) {
        return redirect(route("inicio"));
    }
    if (!auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
        return redirect(route("inicio"));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Posteriormente creo las rutas y las protege con el Middleware que acabo de crear agrego un prefijo para que la ruta sea admin.users ya el controlador depende que se quiera hacer.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => 
['auth']], function () {

/* RUTAS DE ADMIN */
    Route::get('/users/general', 'AdminController@users')
        ->name('users');    
});
```

Para controlar mejor el contenido dentro de un Dashboard y no tener muchos archivos para cada Role creo un Blade personalizada para denegar el acceso a usuarios que no sean ADMIN desde una terminal creo un Provider con el siguiente comando php artisan make:provider AdminServiceProvider y utilizando el método isAdmin del Modelo User.php.

En el ServiceProvider que se acaba de crear y en el método boot se puede utilizar la siguiente lógica

```
public function boot()
{
    \Blade::if('admin', function () {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return auth()->user()->isAdmin();
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Nos dirigimos al directorio Config y en el archivo app.php y en la clave providers agregamos el nuestro:

```
'providers' => [
    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AdminServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Con esto podemos colocar @admin y @endadmin para mostrar contenido solamente al administrador que haya iniciando sesión y los otros usuarios no tendrán acceso.

[image: solamente ver para EDITOR]

[image: eliminar para admin]

Te muestro el resultado de utilizar tu propia directiva Blade personalizada y te muestro el ejemplo de los botones

```
<a
  class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-2"
  href="{{ route("admin.user.show", [$user->id]) 
}}"
 >
 <i class="far fa-eye"></i> {{ __("Ver") }}
  </a>
  @admin
  <a
  class="btn btn-outline-danger delete-record"
  data-route="{{ route("admin.course.destroy", [$user->id]) }}"
  href="#"
  >
  <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> {{ __("Eliminar") }}
   </a>
  @endadmin
```

Así puedes crear las directivas Blade las que necesites y utilizarlas dentro de tus vistas protegiendo botones, rutas, partes de la vista que no deben de ver otros roles. Saludos